# Deity that one prays to in order to get eaten first?

Tags: character-identification

There is a specific sci-fi entity who is worshiped as a god. He will eventually create chaos and devour all humans. The worshipers hope to be eaten first, as they then don't have to witness the horror of the death of the rest of humanity. Who is this deity? I thought it was Cthulhu, but upon further research, I think it may be someone else. Any ideas?

While I have no other information about the mythos, I know that this deity is fairly known in pop culture. I heard about him through a friend and watched a YouTube video that gave the aforementioned description.

Comment: Are there any other details about this deity you remember? Where did you hear about it?

Comment: There is a line in Eben Brooks' incredibly popular parody song "Hey There Cthulhu", 
which is *"So when the stars are right, you'll come and do your worst;
But that's okay because I know you'll eat the cultists like me first"*. 
It may be you saw that, or something referencing that (just because it is so popular.)
That work takes a rather chill approach to "lovecraft mythos" from what I have been told. So "eat cultist like me first" is mostly for the (awesome) sound of the line rather than a particular reference. 
But I'm sure "eat the cultists like me first": is kinda common as a trope.

Comment: http://tsat.transform.to/i.34/cmc.34.mr.html this?

Comment: What YouTube video did you watch? Google seems to imply that it's a common belief that Cthulhu cultists promise that their followers will be given preferential treatment when it comes to devouring (either first or last), but I'm not sure this is ever stated in Lovecraft's original stories (ie. it might not be canon).

Answer (score 12):

It's hard to say without having seen the YouTube video in question, but cultists worshipping the Great Old Ones, of which Cthulhu is the best known, are often described online as promising that their followers will be devoured first (or sometimes last). It seems to be a "meme" of sorts. Examples:

- Cthulhu For President [promises this](http://www.cthulhu.org/cthulhu/positions.html):

  > Cthulhu cultists will be given the following privileges: They will die last.
- [Who Will Be Eaten First?](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=135), a Chick tract parody

  [image: panel from a Cthulhu tract]
- A made-up Cult of Cthulhu card for a made-up "metaphysical card game":

  > Easily offended? Not at all! Those who we don’t like will be kept safe and cozy to witness the full awfulness of the Coming of the Eldritch-Gibbous Elder Gods! Then the cultists will be eaten first, and the others left to slowly perish under the pseudo-pod feet of the implacable Tsathoggua, Shub-Niggurath et al.
- The parody "Wikipedia" Uncyclopedia's article on [Cthulhu](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Cthulhu):

  > The cathedral of the Universal Church of Cthulu, located just outside Providence, Rhode Island (hellmouth-adjacent), offers pot-luck dinners every Saturday, for those who wish to be devoured first.
- The band A Walk With the Wicked's song "Ancient Servant" from the album *Bleated Apocalypse* [includes lines](https://genius.com/A-walk-with-the-wicked-ancient-servant-lyrics) like "The dread god lies entombed / Not dead but dreaming" (a clear reference to *Call of Cthulhu*) and concludes like this:

  > Offering human sacrifice
  >   To gain your favour
  >   Be spared the terrors
  >   And be devoured first
- The online blog article "[Repent, Atheists! Or be devoured by Cthulhu!](https://lovecraftzine.com/2012/03/27/repent-atheists-or-be-devoured-by-cthulhu/)" has [a comment](https://lovecraftzine.com/2012/03/27/repent-atheists-or-be-devoured-by-cthulhu/#comment-4871) which says

  > [...] Actually, believers get devoured first.
- [Random reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordian/comments/2m7ayd/among_the_cultists_ill_be_eaten_first/)'s image caption

These are all just people saying things online without any canon repute, but since you're actually asking what deity a YouTube video referred to, I'm inclined to assume it was Cthulhu based on the widespread notion that his worshippers will be devoured first (or last; at least his cultists promise that cultists will be given preferential treatment, depending on when you prefer to be consumed).

However, I can't find any similar sentiment expressed in any of Lovecraft's original stories, so I'm not sure this belief is canon among the cultists he wrote about. [This forum post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/263-religion/74468035) does assume that this is true "based off HP Lovecraft's work", though, so I might just be bad at searching.

I'm sure this meme originated somewhere, though, so perhaps someone well versed in the Mythos can write a better answer – had your question been "Where did the belief that Cthulhu cultists will be devoured first when he awakens originate?", I'd not have answered, but I still think the deity you're thinking of is Cthulhu.