# Where did the belief originate that Cthulhu cultists will be devoured first?

Tags: history-of, cthulhu-mythos

[image: A panel from a Cthulhu tract]

In [this excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/159976/19561), user tobiasvl remarks

> (...) had your question been "Where did the belief that Cthulhu cultists will be devoured first when he awakens originate?", I'd not have answered (...)

So where *did* the belief originate that Cthulhu cultists will be devoured first?

It doesn't seem part of the original works.

Comment: I think the answer you reference makes it pretty clear that this "belief" is a meme that started online, and not anything that was ever officially part of the "canon" Mythos.  Do you mean to ask what the source of *the meme* is?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it wasn't that Chick tract that started the meme.

Comment: Not really by Chick. See  http://foo.ca/wp/chick-tract-satire/who-will-be-eaten-first/